# images order change in my phone - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

hello i am making a checkers game in android studio and my board buttons order changes when i download it to my phone.

[image from android studios emulator:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs0I8.png)

[how it looks in my phone:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCjcs.jpg)

all lines are reversed on my phone

my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity = "center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box0"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white"
            android:foreground="@drawable/redchecker"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white"
            android:foreground="@drawable/redchecker"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white"
            android:foreground="@drawable/redchecker"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box5"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box6"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white"
            android:foreground="@drawable/redchecker"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/box7"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

ive put only one line because it just repets itself 8 times to create the board.

Comment: Is you phone set to a locale with an RTL language?

Comment: i just noticed that it changes becuase of my native language you were right but how do i change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your phone is in a RTL language.  To force it to layout LTR, add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to the horizontal linear layout (all 8 of them).